# Why does the CPU utilization analyzed by pref is larger than 1？

Tags: linux, perf

```
q@centos:~/QQMail/platform/task/task2>perf stat bazel-bin/test

 Performance counter stats for 'bazel-bin/test':

      16380.991838      task-clock (msec)         #    3.430 CPUs utilized          
           583,363      context-switches          #    0.036 M/sec                  
               227      cpu-migrations            #    0.014 K/sec                  
            37,899      page-faults               #    0.002 M/sec                  
                 0      cycles                    #    0.000 GHz                    
                 0      stalled-cycles-frontend   #    0.00% frontend cycles idle   
                 0      stalled-cycles-backend    #    0.00% backend  cycles idle   
                 0      instructions              #    0.00  insns per cycle        
                 0      branches                  #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 0      branch-misses             #    0.000 K/sec                  

       4.775427302 seconds time elapsed
```

The output is shown above.
I want to know what does the task-clock output by perf mean? Why is it longer than the time elapsed?
And some data are 0, what might be wrong?

Comment: It's not longer, time elapsed is 4.7 seconds, and task-clock is 16380 milliseconds (msec), i.e., 1.6 seconds.

Comment: @Robert: milliseconds are 1/1000ths of a second.  It really is 16.38 CPU-seconds in 4.77 seconds of wall-clock time, on a multi-core machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because time is counted per-CPU, as indicated by the `3.430 CPUs utilized`. It has, on average, occupied 3.43 CPUs during that time. You can check that dividing 16380/3.43 gives you about the elapsed time.